# evaluated boolean return value in mssql - possible?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying:

```
select tbl.*, (true and true) as booleanTest
from tbl
```

which ms-sql doesn't seem to appreciate. **(Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'and')**

Blissed by ignorance I thought this was standard ANSI-something.

Q: Can the above be expressed in a more universal sql syntax?

Comment: SQL Server doesn't have a boolean datatype. Just a `CASE` statement returning `0` or `1` as a `bit`. But `bit` isn't universal either.

Comment: A great answer that is. The problem in a nutshell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL Server does not support standard SQL's `BOOLEAN` data type, remembering it is a very strange kind of Boolean that has three values! In place of `BOOLEAN` literal values you must substitute expressions that evaluate to the required truth value e.g.

```
( 1 = 1 )      -- TRUE
( 0 = 1 )      -- FALSE
( 1 = NULL )   -- UNKNOWN
```

I usually write code like this (following your example):

```
SELECT tbl.*, 
       CASE 
          WHEN     ( ( 1 = 1 ) AND ( 1 = 1 ) ) THEN 'TRUE'
          WHEN NOT ( ( 1 = 1 ) AND ( 1 = 1 ) ) THEN 'FALSE'
          ELSE 'UNKNOWN'
       END AS result
  FROM tbl;
```

---

As @Diego alludes (I think!), in conventional logic we could apply the [idempotence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence) [rewrite rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewriting), which states that

```
( P AND P )   <= is equivalent to =>   ( P )
```

As it happens, the rule holds for SQL's three valued logic.

e.g. proof in SQL Server for the case `( UNKNOWN AND UNKNOWN ) <=> UNKNOWN`:

```
SELECT CASE 
          WHEN     ( 1 = NULL) AND ( 1 = NULL ) THEN 'TRUE'
          WHEN NOT ( 1 = NULL) AND ( 1 = NULL ) THEN 'FALSE'
          ELSE 'UNKNOWN'
       END AS result
```

Comment: I don't think you need 2 comparisons. If either of the parameters are null, it will evaluate to the else

Comment: I meant that ( 1 = 1 ) AND ( 1 = 1 ) is not necessary, you can do only ( 1 = 1). Why would you do 2 comparisons?

Comment: @Diego: Erm, because that is the question, isn't it? You and I may intuitively know what TRUE AND TRUE evaluates to but I figured the point of the exercise is to show what SQL Server thinks the answer is!

Comment: @Diego: on further consideration, you have a point. See update to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

what do you expect to achieve?
There is no boolean on SQl, so you can do something like this:

```
declare @a bit
declare @b bit

set @a=0
set @b=1

select  
    case
        when  @a=@b then 1 
        when  not @a=@b  then 0
        else null
    end as Bool_test
```

possible results:

```
@a              @b        Result
0               0           1
0               1           0
1               0           0
1               1           1
NUll         any_value     NULL
any_value       NULL       NULL
```

Comment: You have forgotten that [SQL exhibits three-valued logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_(SQL)#Three-valued_logic_.283VL.29).

Comment: there is no room for nulls here, but you are right, it would have if 1 and 1 were variables